# Qlikview formular build max sum

Tags: qlikview

Good morning and a happy new year!

I'm looking for a QlikView formular. I don't get the result yet.

What is the problem:

I've loaded the following table incl. data.

structure:

```
customer, netting, month, value
```

data e.g.:

```
1, 44, 201712, 40
1, 44, 201801, 44
1, 45, 201712, 100
1, 45, 201801, 101
2, 30, 201801, 55
2, 30, 201802, 60
2, 31, 201803, 400
2, 31, 201804, 380
```

The QlikView formular should sum up at first all month values for the respective customer and nettings, afterwards built the max of all month for all customer.

For customer 1 it is 141 due to the fact that the sum month 201712 is 140 and the sum of 201801 is 141. The max of the example is the 141.

For customer 2 is it 400.

Over all customers is 541 the value which I have to report - sum of all max.

The table contains ~12000 customers which monthly profile till end of 2030. ... and of course a lot of nettings.

Any idea how to built such a formula within QlikView.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Best regards

Andreas

Comment: You seem to have an error in your example. For customer 1 the value should be 145 and not 141, right? (44+101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a pivot table that has "customer" as a dimension and the following expressions:

```
Max(Aggr(Sum(netting), month, customer))
Max(Aggr(Sum(value), month, customer))
```

Name for instance the first one as "Netting" and the second one as "Value". Make sure that in the Expression tab, on the Total Mode options you have selected "Sum of Rows" (Sum coming from the dropdown).

The expression reads as you've described the issue. You want the max value you can obtain by summing the netting/value field and aggregating them by customer and month.

Happy 2018!

Comment: Thank you very much! You made my day :o)